# Individual group sum and total column sum

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

How can I show individual group sum and total sum of a column for angular js ng Table?
http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/12.

Comment: Do you have any code to show? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Pl find http://plnkr.co/edit/bBEaw23QXqwuwjaBegEw?p=preview. For Total1, Total2, Total3 columns I want group sum and total sum. Till now I was using smart table for which they provided steps to get total sum. As I can't do grouping there, recently I shifted to ngtable. I searched for sample codes to get group sum and total sum. But I did  not find any reference. One way I can do it is, to prepare the json itself with these details, which I don't want. Instead, with the existing json itself, I want to get these sums by tweaking ngtable settings, if possible, and I am looking reference for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/LP5hLVYh0OIfMNBKpRxk?p=preview) that present how you can show group sum (for example sum of all ages of people).

Check function `$scope.GetSummOfAges` in controller.

**Detailed explanation**
Instead of applying *ng-repeat* directive for *$data* variable ,you first need to apply that for groups of item (*$groups* var) and then there second nested *ng-repeat* for items in each group ,and thus near nested directive you can apply any function for group items,like here

### Index.html

```
<tbody ng-repeat="group in $groups">
        <tr class="ng-table-group">
            <td colspan="{{$columns.length}}">
                <a >
                    <<strong>{{ group.value }}</strong>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in group.data">
            <td sortable="name" data-title="'Name'">
                {{user.name}}
            </td>
            <td sortable="age" data-title="'Age'">
                {{user.age}}
            </td>
        </tr>
       <tr><td><b>summ of ages</b></td><td>{{GetSummOfAges(group)}}</td></tr>        
    </tbody>
```

### App.js

```
$scope.GetSummOfAges=function(group){
      var summ=0;
      for(var i in group.data)
      {
        summ=summ+Number(group.data[i].age);
      }
      return summ;
    };
```

#### Note:

since Angular 1.2 you better use *[ng-repeat-start](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)* to propagate *`<tr>`* tag,instead of *`<tbody>`* tag like in example

Comment: help me out with links to plunk,pls,i cant figure out

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: thanks for valuable advice,i will edit answer as soon as i can

Comment: where i can get info about plunk links formatting,it's not working out for me